# How can I follow the current in this DW01A circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, lithium-ion, diy, bms

I try to understand the inner logic of this diagram, this a modified version of a schematic that I found online. I made the necessary calculations for my power MOSFETs and all but I have some questions.

[image]

Before making the calculations here are the specs of MMBT3906 Transistor

hfe = 100

Vce(sat) = -0.25V

Vbe(sat) = -0.65V

when OD and OC pins (1&3) are low then the calculations for MMBT3906 Transistors are as follows

[image]

Let's say that we did this calculation for the transistor connected to pin 1 so the Ic is 3.4uA. Then what happens?

It is said that this 3.4uA eventually drives the NPN MMBT3904 transistor and switches the MOSFETs but how?
Also, what is the purpose of those 10M resistors and the capacitor (0.47uF)?

I am more interested in those transistors then the HY2213 circuitry, so please, can someone explain this to me thoroughly?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess for your consideration as you seem to be way more knowledgeable than me.

The R004 chips near the B- are current sensors Network that basically drives the MOSFETs permanently thus removing the load from the DW01A Chip this diagram is the opposite of what usually you find from the DW01A Chip datasheet so that when pin 1 (Low Voltage Sensed) goes high It will Connect the MOSFETs and when Low (Normal operation will Disconnect them).

| DW01A Pin 1 | MMBT3906 | MMBT3904 | P75N02LD Left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | OFF | ON | ON |
| L | ON | OFF | OFF |

When a cell is Low, Discharge is disallowed. Unless you have power coming in from P- which will drive the Left side MOSFETS back In to allow recharge the Cells.

I believe the reason they made this circuit like so (in opposite connection stealing current for driving components) is because if the DW01A fails (Thus permanently setting pin 1 or 3 Low) the BMS will also disconnect the Cell and effectively prevent more damage to the pack.

I hope that someone knowledgeable can jump in and further clarify the functionality.